# The relation $\cong$ an equivalence relation on nonempty collection of groups $\mathcal{G}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

The following text is given in Dummit and Foote (pg-$37$) as example of isomorphism:

> For any group $G$, $G \cong G$. The identity map provides an obvious
>   isomorphism but not, in general, the *only* isomorphism from $G$ to
>   itself. More generally, let $\mathcal{G}$ be any nonempty collection
>   of groups. It is easy to check that the relation $\cong$ is an
>   equivalence relation on $\mathcal{G}$ and the equivalence classes are
>   called *isomorphism classes*. This accounts for the somewhat symmetric
>   wording of the definition of "isomorphism."

I am able to understand on considering individual groups, but can anybody elaborate/sketch a proof how is the relation $\cong$ an equivalence relation on nonempty collection of groups $\mathcal{G}$?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the definition of equivalence relation? You just check that the relation given by $G\cong H\iff \text{there is an isomorphism }f:G\to H$ satisfies the definition of equivalence relation.

Comment: Reflexivity is already covered, too.

Comment: I know the definition of equivalence relation; it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. When $G \cong G$, it satisfies reflexivity. When $G \cong H$, implies $H \cong G$, it satisfies symmetry. When $G \cong H$ and $H \cong J$, then it implies $G \cong J$ and hence transitivity is satisfied. Hence the relation $\cong$ is an equivalence relation. I want to ask what do they mean when they say equivalence relation on nonempty COLLECTION of groups...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your misunderstanding lies in the definition of either *equivalence relation* or *collection*. By the latter, they simply mean a [set or proper class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_class). Let me try to explain the former in this context.

---

Let $\mathcal G$ be a collection of groups (it doesn't actually have to be non-empty). Then $\cong$ is a reflexive relation on $\mathcal G,$ meaning that for ***every*** $G\in\mathcal G,$ we have $G\cong G.$ Also, $\cong$ is a symmetric relation on $\mathcal G,$ meaning that for ***every*** $G,H\in\mathcal G,$ if $G\cong H,$ then we have $H\cong G.$ Finally, $\cong$ is a transitive relation on $\mathcal G,$ meaning that for ***every*** $G,H,K\in\mathcal G,$ if $G\cong H$ and $H\cong K,$ then we have $G\cong K.$ *That* is what it means for $\cong$ to be an equivalence relation on $\mathcal G.$ (Note that if $\mathcal G$ is empty, then all of the above hold vacuously.)

---

Now, let me try to illustrate how this differs from the definitions you posited in the comments above. I will address your proposed definition of reflexivity, specifically (and if I think of amy straightforward means of addressing the other two, I'll add that in).

Consider the relation $G\simeq'H,$ by which we will denote that $G\cong Z(H),$ where $Z(H)$ is the *center* of $H.$ Readily, then, if you let $G$ be your favorite cyclic group (or any abelian group), then we have $G\simeq'G.$ However, $\simeq'$ is *not* (in general) a reflexive relation, since (for example, is it *false* that $S_3\simeq' S_3.$ In fact, we can only say that $\simeq'$ is reflexive among abelian groups.

Comment: I think I got your point... Thanks.......I want to clarify that in the last line did you mean $\simeq'$ is reflexive instead of $\simeq$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

As already shown, $G\cong G$ per $\operatorname{id}_G$.

If $G\cong H$ via an isomorphism $\phi\colon G\to H$, recall that this means by definition that there exists a homomorphism $\psi\colon H\to G$ with $\phi\circ \psi=\operatorname{id}_H$ and $\psi\circ \phi=\operatorname{id}_G$. This again means that $\psi$ is an isomorphsim, so $H\cong G$.

Finally, if $G\cong H$ via $\phi$ and $H\cong K$ via $\psi$, then $G\cong K$ via $\psi\circ \phi$, where the proof that $\psi\circ \phi$ is an isomorphism is just as straightforward.